# Node Visibility Within Layer

Tags: qgis

Is there a way within QGIS to hide/display (freeze/thaw) an individual node feature within a layer or does this control only exist at the layer level.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: being new to QGIS, I am trying to figure out how to display certain features within a given layer. As an example i have a layer with several hiking routes in it. i want to display only 1 or 2 of them in a finished product.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for my english :

in Mapinfo, this is a "pochoir"...

This morning i ask me this question :

to show or mask one node in a layer , i think you have to make one "sous-ensemble"... with the property of the layer : onglet "general" "constructeur de requête" and not a selection.

The "sous-ensemble" is concervated in the project, the selection no.

Marc

Comment: thank you marc, i have suspected that grouping might be the answer, just haven't figured out how to do it yet. i will look into it.